# How to open .coverage file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, perfmon

I have created a `.coverage` file using `Vsperfmon.exe`

I am currently using `VS 2012 professional for web` licensed edition. The `.coverage` result cannot be opened in `VS Professional`. After Googling I have come to know that `VS Ultimate` can open it

Rather than using `VS Ultimate`, is there any plugins for `VS professional 2012` or any 3rd party solutions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've spent some time researching this today, as I'm in a similar situation; I have a .coverage file generated by TFS, and VS 2012 Pro, and I can't view the file. As far as I can tell, the answer is "You need VS Premium or Ultimate to view .coverage files."

I found https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator, which generates reports based on XML-formatted coverage files. It includes instructions for converting .coverage to XML (see https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator/wiki/Visual-Studio-Coverage-Tools), but that process depends on `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis` which isn't present in VS Pro.

Comment: That is how i worked. But unfortunatly license for VS Ultimate expired.So I am in the middle of nowhere and because of that I dropped my idea of code coverage temporarly

Comment: If you're looking for a free (as in beer) solution, try OpenCover (https://github.com/sawilde/opencover/) with ReportGenerator. I was able to get a coverage report from my MSTest unit tests using those tools. However, I'm not sure I can integrate those with our Visual Studio Online build.

Comment: ReportGenerator has moved from CodePlex to GitHub. Instructions for converting .coverage to .xml are now here: https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator/wiki/Visual-Studio-Coverage-Tools

Comment: Even if you only have a Professional license, you may have Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis.dll on your system. E.g. in \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform or similar

Answer (score 2):

Another tool I came to know to convert .coverage file to readable format is [Visual Coverage](https://github.com/jsargiot/visual-coverage) .This converts into html

Comment: This requires VS Enterprise (https://github.com/jsargiot/visual-coverage#prerequisites).